# Synchronous control flow using coroutine in Javascript

Tags: javascript, coroutine

I want to know if we can implement a function which can block in Javascript. For example:

```
var username = getUserName(); //wait for user input username in a certain way
doSth(username);
```

I hope getUserName can block until a valid username is input by the user. I am wondering if we could use coroutine or other ways to achieve this goal. Thank you.

Comment: You could use the Javascript `prompt()` function.

Comment: How do you want the input from the user?

Comment: In some browsers, you can have a *modal* input with non-standard [`showModalDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536759(v=vs.85).aspx). I would not recommended doing this, though.

Answer (score 1):

In the browser, the closest you are going to get to coroutines are the Python-like [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) proposed in the Ecmascript 6 standard. However, only Firefox and the bleeding edge versions of NodeJs natively support them as of today.

Given that most browsers don't support coroutines (and won't for a long time because of old versions of IE), your best bet is using a pure-Javascript control-flow library (seee "async.js" or promises) or use some tool that compiles a dialect of Javascript extended with coroutines back into continuation-passing-style. There are a couple that use the ES6 syntax and some others that use different syntaxes (and there are also some non-JS languages compiling to Javascript)

Finally, to keep things complete, in Nodejs has a Fibers feature that is a bit similar to coroutines but its server-side-only so I don't think they are going to be very useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't "blocking" but you could always use a callback

```
function getUsername(done) {
  try {
    var username = // some process that gets the username;
    return done(null, username);
  }
  catch (err) {
    return done(err);
  }
}

getUsername(function(err, username) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(username);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whith the arriving of generators to javascript and the help of [Aryn](https://github.com/yosbelms/aryn) is possible to use coroutines and CSP(Communicating Sequential Processes) in Node.js or in the client-side.

Aryn + Promise example in Node.js:

```
function getUsername(id) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        db.query('select username from user where id = ?', [id], function(r){
            resolve(r[0].username)
        })
    })
}

// your coroutine
aryn.run(function*(){
    var username = yield getUsername(id)
    console.log(username)
})
```

Using Aryns `drive` function:

```
db = aryn.drive(require('db'))

var getUsername = aryn.def(function*(){
    return yield aryn.receive(db.query('select username from user where id = ?', [id]))
})

aryn.run(function*(){
    var username = yield getUsername(id)
    console.log(username)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

A CSP fan here. I spent like half a year working on CSP in JavaScript solution and I think I'm somewhere with this. If you are interested check [Riew](https://github.com/krasimir/riew).